# How to capture the output of a bash command into a variable when using pipes and apostrophe?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I am not sure how to save the output of a command via bash into a variable:

```
PID = 'ps -ef | grep -v color=auto | grep raspivid | awk '{print $2}''
```

Do I have to use a special character for the apostrophe or for the pipes?

Thanks!

Comment: In this pipeline, what is the `grep -v color=auto` command intended to accomplish?

Comment: exclude from the results the search process itself which always has the color=auto parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture the output of a command in shell, use command substitution: `$(...)`.  Thus:

```
pid=$(ps -ef | grep -v color=auto | grep raspivid | awk '{print $2}')
```

#### Notes

- When making an assignment in shell, there must be no spaces around the equal sign.
- When defining shell variables for local use, it is best practice to use lower case or mixed case.  Variables that are important to the system are defined in upper case and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.

#### Simplification

If the goal is to get the PID of the `raspivid` process, then the `grep` and `awk` can be combined into a single process:

```
pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/[r]aspivid/{print $2}')
```

Note the simple trick that excludes the current process from the output:  instead of searching for `raspivid` we search for `[r]aspivid`.  The string `[r]aspivid` does not match the regular expression `[r]aspivid`.  Hence the current process is removed from the output.

#### The Flexibility of `awk`

For the purpose of showing how `awk` can replace multiple calls to `grep`, consider this scenario: suppose that we want to find lines that contain `raspivid` but that do *not* contain `color=auto`.  With `awk`, both conditions can be combined logically:

```
pid=$(ps -ef  | awk '/raspivid/ && !/color=auto/{print $2}')
```

Here, `/raspivid/` requires a match with `raspivid`.  The `&&` symbol means logical "and".  The `!` before the regex `/color=auto/` means logical "not".  Thus, `/raspivid/ && !/color=auto/` matches only on lines that contain `raspivid` but not `color=auto`.

Comment: John1024 - The search itself comes as a result too, therefore I need to filter out the color=auto parameter. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @user1688175 OK.  There is a nice trick for removing the current process from the match.  I added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward approach:

`pid=$(pgrep raspivid)`

... or a little different

echo `pgrep [t]eleport`